# Is existing file removed when a symlink is created with the same name?

Tags: linux, shell, ln

So there was a file `dummy1`. I created a symlink:

```
ln -snf dummy dummy1
```

and confused source and target file, as I actually wanted `dummy` to point to `dummy1` not vice versa.
So now `dummy1` is a symlink.

Is the original `dummy1` file removed by doing this? Any way to get it back?

I would expect to get it back somehow, because otherwise that would be strange, as even `rm` command asks for confirmation.

Thank you

Comment: See [Create symlink - overwrite if one exists](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207294/create-symlink-overwrite-if-one-exists) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you have a backup of `dummy1`! From the man page for `ln`:

```
   -f, --force
          remove existing destination files
```

So `dummy1` has been removed and replaced by the symlink.

If you want to prevent this in the future, do **not** use the `-f` flag to `ln`.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! I actually checked man, but on my mac, which says `-f    If the target file already exists, then unlink it so that the link may occur.` So it was not clear for me that it was removed and I didn't know that on linux (which is the question about) it says differently

Comment: @rightaway717 "unlink" means "remove" in the Unix world.

Comment: @StephenKitt good to know that now, though too late. I didn't know there is such a command, thanx